# Probability measure, probability density function or probability event ? Are they different?

Tags: probability, information-theory

My question is regarding the difference between probability measure and probability of event.

Recently I have read an information theory paper that considered a channel modeled by probability density function (pdf) $$\mathbb{P}(Y_1\mid X_1)$$
The exact words of the paper are:

*A memoryless channel with joint transition probability distributions (or conditional channel distribution:  $\mathbb{P}(Y\mid X)$*

*while the probability of decoding error is defined as*

$$\mathbb{P}[\widehat{W} \not= W]$$

I am wondering is there any difference between the two definitions of probability. As you can see one used the paranthesis P() and the other definition used the bracket P[] notation.

Thanks looking forward for your answers.

Comment: The notations appeared in your paper are not standard. But may be considered as an "abuse of notation". After all, non-standard but acceptable notations are used everywhere.

Comment: The notations were not defined. So I assumed they are standards. Do you believe they are refering to different meanings of probability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is often an abuse of notation,

One writes $P[X \in A]$ to mean $P(\{\omega: X(\omega) \in A\})$ In the same sense for $B \subset \Omega$  measurable set one writes $P(B)$ to mean the probability of the event $B$. The notation is quite similar and one might find them misplaced.

But as it is a notation  issue, one must be prepared to find different conventions and to adapt and interpret the different representations.

Comment: thank you. So do you believe the authors used, paranthesis to denote brackets to denote the probability of event $\widehat{W}\neq W$ which is an event? While they used paranthesis to denote pdf i.e $P(Y|X)$... i.e are these two different?